# Android Java Strings

Tags: java, android

For Strings..

How can i Detect if the string "name" has the text "Hello" a toast will come up saying yes but if it doesn't a toast will come up saying no?
my code:

```
        String ft;
    if(ft.contains("Hello")){

        Toast.makeText(main.this ,"Yes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else{
        Toast.makeText(main.this ,"No", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

I get a error at ft on if(ft.contains("Hello")) {

"The local variable ft may not have been initialized"

Comment: You have to initialize `String` empty. try `String ft="";`

Comment: Thanks Kartik it worked, question will this save when the user closes the application and when they reopen it will be changed to whatever i put?

Comment: Let me resay that how can i change the string to be false after they click on my button?

Comment: question will this save when the user closes the application and when they reopen it will be changed to whatever i put?--- No it will be destroyed when you exit from application. Either you use Static String or SharedPreferences(if they are too important for you)

Comment: Yes, it's important i need it how could i do this?

Comment: You can go thru : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref and http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/63.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared `String`, but you didn't initialize. Initializing it is setting them equal to a value:

```
String ft;        // This is a declaration

String ft="";    // This is an initialization
```

Perhaps `String ft = "";` is "declaration and initialization.

You get the error because you haven't initialized the variable, but you use them (e.g., ft.compare()) in if condition.

So try replacing 
`String ft;` with `String ft="";`

Answer (score 2):

```
String text;
if(name.equals("Hello")){
    text = "Yes";
} else {
    text = "No";
}

Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
toast.show();
```

You can also use shorthand expression instead of `if`:

```
String text = name.equals("Hello") ? "Yes" : "No";
```

Comment: Why not all in one line?
Toast.makeText(context, (name.equals("Hello") ? "Yes" : "No"), duration).show();

Comment: String ft;
        if(ft.equals("Hello")){
            ft = "Yes";
        } else {
            ft = "No";
        }


i get a error under the ft at ft.equals "The local variable ft may not have been initialized"

Comment: This is gonna throw a compile time error... it is't right.. "text" should have atleast blank string value initially...

Comment: @Hailei: should be `name.equals("Hello")` not `ft`

Comment: My string name is FT not name

Comment: Also i dont want it to just change the text.. i want it to beable i put code in it like image.setVisibility(0); or something

Answer (score 1):

```
if(name.contains("Hello")){

Toast.makeText(activity.this ,"Yes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
else{
Toast.makeText(activity.this ,"No", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

**Updated:**

```
String ft = "";

    String ft= name.equals("Hello") ? "Yes" : "No";
     Toast.makeText(activity.this ,ft, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: The local variable ft may not have been initialized under if(ft.contains

Comment: @HaileiEdwards: change `String ft;` to `String ft="";` or `String ft=null;` whatever suites best in your case.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(name.equals("Hello")){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Yes", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}else{
     Toast.makeText(this, "no", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```